# how to pass element which was clicked - Jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
(function ($) {
    function App() {
        this.init();

    }
    App.prototype.findSideBarLink = function(){
        $('#sidebar .list a[href*="'+ $(this).attr("href") +'"]').click();
    };
    App.prototype.init = function () {
        $('.column-header a').click(this.findSideBarLink());
        $('.column .column__more').click(this.findSideBarLink());
    }
}
```

I want to read in findSideBarLink function the element which was clicked. $(this) is not working. any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function reference as click event handler

```
App.prototype.init = function () {
    $('.column-header a').click(this.findSideBarLink);
    $('.column .column__more').click(this.findSideBarLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$("selector").click(function() {
  $(this).doSomething();
});
```